# override a method and add a method with same signature but another return type

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance

Given IGeometry interface with CreateTransformedCopy method, Curve abstract class and Line class. Curve implements IGeometry and Line inherits Curve. The idea is to have a possibility to use the CreateTransformedCopy method with object of each class/interface with the following return type:

- Have IGeometry object => get IGeometry object
- Have Curve object => get IGeometry object if cast Curve to IGeometry or a specific Curve object
- Have Line object => get Curve if cast Line to Curve or a specific Line object

**Important: only class that inherits from Curve knows how to create a copy** (I want to have line, circe and other classes that inherit from Curve and provide specific implementation).

PS maybe you can recomend me some book/cource that can help me to solve such OOP problems (Im not new to OOP but probably lack some knoledge)

Thank you!

I tried the code below but I get error in Line class stating that there exist a member with the same signature.

```
public interface IGeometry : ISpatial
{
    public IGeometry CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix);
}

public abstract class Curve : IGeometry
{
    public abstract Curve CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix);

    IGeometry IGeometry.CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix) 
    => CreateTransformedCopy(transformationMatrix);
}

public class Line : Curve
{
    public new Line CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix)
    {
    return new Line(***implementation details***);
    }

    public override Curve CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix)
    => CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix);
}
```

Comment: Look up the recent C# feature called _Covariant Return Types_.  I don't know enough about how the C# implementation works to explain things to you, but it may provide a solution to your problem

Comment: I don’t understand the use case here. You can call `CreateTransformedCopy` to return a line, then cast it back to a curve?

Comment: @stuartd for example I have some objects of different types. Let it be a Line and a Cirle objects. I want to make array of Curve add Line and Circle objects to it and iterate over the array creating transformed curves. This calls Curve.CreateTransformedCopy and creates a Curve object. But I still want to have a CreateTransformedCopy method in Line and Circle class that returns specific Line or Circle.

Comment: @Flydog57 Covariant Return Types is exactly what I need but this feature is not supported in .net standart

Answer (score 2):

**Ignore this answer - it is incorrect and will be deleted**

This doesn't answer the question, but it is in response to your comment that *"Covariant Return Types is exactly what I need but this feature is not supported in .NET Standard*".

I just whipped up a *Class Library* Test project targeting .NET Standard (on .NET 6) containing this code.  It compiled:

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual Animal GetAnimal()
    {
        return new Animal();
    }
}

public class Fox : Animal
{
    public override Fox GetAnimal()
    {
        return new Fox();
    }
}

public class RedFox : Fox
{
    public override RedFox GetAnimal()
    {
        return new RedFox();
    }
}

public class Elephant : Animal
{
    public override Elephant GetAnimal()
    {
        return new Elephant();
    }
}
```

It appears that *Covariant Return Types* works on .NET Standard.  I don't know if this helps you answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for response! It seems like this is what I need but I don't understand how can I create a library that targets .NET Standard on .NET6. When creating a new class library in VIsual Studio 2022 I can choose eather .NET Standard or .NET6.

Comment: Sorry, I must have mis-clicked on something as I was setting this up.  If I try to re-create your problem, I get the following error: `error CS8830: 'Fox.GetAnimal()': Target runtime doesn't support covariant return types in overrides. Return type must be 'Animal' to match overridden member 'Animal.GetAnimal()'`.  I'll be deleting this answer sometime in the next day

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing here is because of how explicit and implicit interfaces work in C#. When you provide explicit interface implementation in the Curve class, it hides that implementation from classes that derive from Curve. In other words, the Line class does not see the explicit implementation of IGeometry.CreateTransformedCopy, thus it can't override it.

One way to achieve what you're trying to do is to provide explicit interface implementation in all the classes, like this:

```
public interface IGeometry
{
    IGeometry CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix);
}

public abstract class Curve : IGeometry
{
    public abstract Curve CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix);

    IGeometry IGeometry.CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix) 
        => CreateTransformedCopy(transformationMatrix);
}

public class Line : Curve
{
    public override Curve CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix)
    {
        // ***implementation details***
        return new Line();
    }

    IGeometry IGeometry.CreateTransformedCopy(Matrix transformationMatrix)
        => CreateTransformedCopy(transformationMatrix);
}
```

In this case, the Line class provides explicit implementation for IGeometry.CreateTransformedCopy that delegates the call to its own CreateTransformedCopy method. The CreateTransformedCopy method in Line class returns a Line instance, which satisfies the requirement to return a Curve instance. At the same time, it also provides a more specific type for consumers that are aware of the Line class.

As for learning more about OOP, one great resource is the book "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides (the "Gang of Four"). This book provides a good introduction to many common object-oriented design patterns and principles. Another great resource is "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship" by Robert C. Martin, which has some great insights on designing and organizing code in an object-oriented way.

Comment: This is AI generated, which is forbidden on Stack Overflow. Please delete it before you get yourself into more trouble: we take plagiarism seriously here.